# Conditional validations in angular2

Tags: angular, validation, typescript

I want to use same template for guest and customer registration forms but validations may varies as follows

Let us assume it is a Register form for Guests - firstName is required

```
<form #f="ngForm" novalidate (ngSubmit)="save()">
                <label>First Name:</label>
                <input type="text" name="firstName" [(ngModel)]="values.FirstName" required #firstName="ngModel">
                <div *ngIf="firstName.hasError('required') && (!firstName.pristine && !f.submitted)" class="text-danger">You must include a first name.</div>
</form>
```

And this is for Customer - firstName is optional

```
<form #f="ngForm" novalidate (ngSubmit)="save()">
                    <label>First Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="firstName" [(ngModel)]="values.FirstName" #firstName="ngModel">

</form>
```

I want to use same/onlyone template for both forms but validations varies! how could i achieve it. TIA!

> NOTE: by using reactive forms I could achieve it, but knowingly I want
>   to achieve in Template-Driven forms.

Answer (score 6):

Based on this [topic](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7644) you can try

```
<input name="first" ngModel [required]="isRequired">
```

Comment: That's great, I'll give a shot and let you know.

Comment: Tim as you said it working but what about if we had multiple validations like min max etc for same field. In those scenarios how would we neglect min-length else max length validations as well. is there any way for it ?