# How to conditionally require form inputs in angular 4?

Tags: forms, angular, validation

I am using template driven forms for adding the task, and there are 2 input fields of type number for estimated mins to complete task,

- one field is for estimated number of hrs and
- another is for estimated minutes to complete the task

since the task estimate can be done either in hours like **1hrs** , or in hours and minutes like **1Hrs 30Mins** , so i want to set attribute **required** to inputs conditionally. So one of the 2 inputs must be set or form validation error will occur if both inputs are empty when submitting form.

so far i have done this but validation is not working

```
<form class="add-task" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(newtask)" #newtask="ngForm">  
    <div class="estimate-container">
        <input 
            type="number" 
            min="0" 
            max="10" 
            id="estimate_hrs" 
            ngModel 
            name="estimate_hrs"
            mdInput 
            [required]="!estimateMins.valid" 
            placeholder="Estimated Hours" 
            #estimateHrs="ngModel"
        >
        <div class="error-msg" *ngIf="!estimateHrs.valid && !estimateMins.valid">
            Please enter estimated hours 
        </div>
        <input 
            type="number" 
            min="0" 
            max="60" 
            id="estimate_min" 
            ngModel 
            name="estimate_min" 
            mdInput 
            [required]="!estimateHrs.valid" 
            placeholder="Estimated Minutes" 
            #estimateMins="ngModel"
        >
        <div class="error-msg" *ngIf="!estimateMins.valid && !estimateHrs.valid">
            Please enter estimated minutes
        </div>   
    </div>
    <button type='submit' [disabled]="!newtask.valid" >Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 17):

Try using [attr.required] instead.

```
   <input 
        type="number" 
        min="0" 
        max="10" 
        id="estimate_hrs" 
        ngModel 
        name="estimate_hrs"
        mdInput 
        [attr.required]="!estimateMins.valid" 
        placeholder="Estimated Hours" 
        #estimateHrs="ngModel"
    >
```

Comment: could you look in to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44024833/conditional-validations-in-angular2)

Comment: The OP said that was not working hence I thought they could try the alternate syntax ..,

Comment: did you went through the link?, it was a question. Is there way to solve it in template driven forms?

Comment: thank you for taking your time to answer this , but it didn't worked , so is my only option is to implement reactive forms ?.

Comment: Have you tried simplifying the code to the basics just to be sure that is the problem? Try taking off all of the other attributes and see if that changes anything. Also, could you do a plunker that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: I just did a plunker here and the basic syntax seems to work fine: https://plnkr.co/edit/QAqeBYrg19dXcqbubVZ8?p=preview So I think your problem may be somewhere else (not the required attribute) OR what you are binding to.

Answer (score 17):

This is my working solution for Angular 5:

In component:

```
@Input()
required: boolean;
```

In template on the input (or select) element that:

```
[required]="required"
```

On the selector:

```
[required]="true"
```

Like @DeborahK double checked, no need for single quotes :-)

Comment: by adding single quotes it works for me otherwise its not working

Answer (score 9):

You need to put your `!estimateMins.valid` in single quotes like:

`[required]="'!estimateMins.valid'"` and `[required]="'!estimateHrs.valid'"`

See this [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/rL0l42nsl7eQHAd4S4p9)

Comment: The recent version of angular(and perhaps a few earlier ones) does not require single quotes inside the statement. Therefore, [required]="!estimateMins.valid" will work.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `[required]=boolean`.

Answer (score 2):

I spent some time trying this out because the basic syntax should have worked. I initially did a simply plunker just to test the syntax and the syntax does indeed work as defined.

After expanding the plunker to more closely match the OP's code: https://plnkr.co/edit/QAqeBYrg19dXcqbubVZ8?p=preview

```
<Links to plunker must be accompanied by code>
```

It became apparent that it is *not* a syntax error. Rather it is a logic error.

When the form first appears, both controls are valid so neither of them have the required attribute. So then neither are required and it appears that it does not work.

There are several possible ways to resolve this. One is to build a custom validator that does the cross field validation.

Comment: thank you for your time , later i changed it to reactive form and made array of custom  validators for different scenarios , like also for checking the min max value of form controls and displaying errors according to that

Answer (score 0):

In angular2 or above you can use `ngNativeValidate` directive for `template driven` form. And also `object` to reserved and sending data(though it's your personal choice but i love this way) to api.

```
<form class="add-task" #newtask="ngForm" ngNativeValidate (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">  

    <div class="estimate-container">
        <input 
            type="number" 
            min="0" 
            max="10" 
            id="estimate_hrs" 
            name="estimate_hrs"
            mdInput 
            [required]="!taskModel.estimateMins" 
            placeholder="Estimated Hours" 
            [(ngModel)]="taskModel.estimateHrs">

        <div class="error-msg" *ngIf="!taskModel.estimateHrs && !taskModel.estimateMins">
            Please enter estimated hours 
        </div>
        <input 
            type="number" 
            min="0" 
            max="60" 
            id="estimate_min" 
            name="estimate_min" 
            mdInput 
            [required]="!taskModel.estimateHrs" 
            placeholder="Estimated Minutes" 
            [(ngModel)]="taskModel.estimateMins">

        <div class="error-msg" *ngIf="!taskModel.estimateMins && !taskModel.estimateHrs">
            Please enter estimated minutes
        </div>   
    </div>
    <button type='submit' [disabled]="!newtask.valid" [isFormValid]="!newtask.valid">Submit</button>
</form>
```

In `.ts` file

```
taskModel: any;

onSubmit(){
    
    console.log(this.taskModel) // this object has all data.
}
```

You can also achieve the same with in `AngularJS (version 1.x)`

```
<form id="form" name="form" class="add-task" ng-init="taskModel={}">

    <div class="estimate-container">
        <input 
            type="number" 
            min="0" 
            max="10" 
            id="estimate_hrs" 
            name="estimate_hrs"
            mdInput 
            ng-required="!taskModel.estimateMins" 
            placeholder="Estimated Hours" 
            ng-model="taskModel.estimateHrs">

        <div class="error-msg" ng-if="!taskModel.estimateHrs && !taskModel.estimateMins">
            Please enter estimated hours 
        </div>
        <input 
            type="number" 
            min="0" 
            max="60" 
            id="estimate_min" 
            name="estimate_min" 
            mdInput 
            ng-required="!taskModel.estimateHrs" 
            placeholder="Estimated Minutes" 
            ng-model="taskModel.estimateMins">

        <div class="error-msg" ng-if="!taskModel.estimateMins && !taskModel.estimateHrs">
            Please enter estimated minutes
        </div>   
    </div>
    <button ng-disabled="form.$valid" ng-click="form.$valid && onSubmit()" >Submit</button>
</form>
```

Hope it's helpful to you!